# Ajax, json url only specific data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm using this function

```
var url = 'XXXXXXXX'
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: "json",
          //  data: {Calling:Calling},
            processData: false,
            crossDomain: true,
            jsonp: false,
            url: url,
    success: displayAll
});
        function displayAll(r,data){
            for( i in r.Events )
                {           
                    var eventType    = r.Events[i].Event
                    var eventData    = r.Events[i].Data
                    var eventDetails = r.Events[i].Details
                    var caller = r.Events[i].Data.Calling

                    var test = JSON.stringify(caller);
                    console.log(test);
  }
```

The json XXX URL returns something like

```
 >Data: {
 >    Billing: "0033912312312" (OVH number)
 >    Body: "SIP/2.0 200 OK" (Header SIP packet)
 >    CallId: "N2ZkZmEyNGMxZWM0N2VhN2M4NGJkMTY4ZGYwZmU2OTY." (CallId identifier)
 >    Called: "0033912312312" (calling number)
 >    Calling: "0033912312312" (L'appelant)
 >    Cseq: "181 REGISTER" (Le code CSeq du paquet SIP)
 >    DateStart: Thu Mar 05 2015 12:44:30 GMT+0100 (CET) (La date)
 >    Dialed: "0033912312312" (Le numéro composé)
 >    Event: "registered" (Le type d'évenement)
 >    Protocol: "sip" (Le type de protocole, sip ou mgcp)
 >    RelevantInfo: "" (Information importante)
 >    Ts: 1425554670.102
 >    TsGet: 1425554670238926800 (Le timestamp de l'évenement en nanoseconde)
>}
>Date: "2015-03-05T12:24:30.255954 (CET)"
 >Details: {
 >    Description: "Gaelle Becquet" (Description du numéro OVH)
 >    Id: "295670" (Identifiant de la ligne du numéro OVH)
>    IdBillingAccount: "59415" (Identifiant du groupe du numéro OVH)
 >    SimultaneousLine: "2" (Nombre de lignes simultannées)
>    Type: "sipCirpack" (Type de ligne)
 >}
>Event: "registered" (Le type d'évenement)
>Ressource: "0033912312312" (Le numéro OVH)
>Service: "sip" (Le protocole)
>Timestamp: 1425554670255954700 (Le timestamp de l'évenement en nanoseconde)
>Token: "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX" (Le token)
```

I need to get the value of `Calling` and `Called` to re use it in sql query.

i've tried using

```
    data: {Calling:Calling, Called:Called},
```

in the ajax function but since im getting the result from url
console returns

```
 ReferenceError: Calling is not defined
```

is there a way to pass it to php with `data:` ? or maybe an alternative (twig?)

---

EDIT : 
here is what i've tried

```
   var url = 'xx'

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: "json",
            //data: {Calling:Calling},
            processData: false,
            crossDomain: true,
            jsonp: false,
            url: url,
    success: displayAll


});

        function displayAll(r,data){
            for( i in r.Events )
                {
                    // Sotre in last events
                    var eventType    = r.Events[i].Event
                    var eventData    = r.Events[i].Data
                    var eventDetails = r.Events[i].Details
                    var caller = r.Events[i].Data.Calling

                    var test = JSON.stringify(caller);
                    console.log(test);
                    console.log(this);
                    var json = JSON.parse(test);
       $.ajax(
{
    url: 'test.php',
    type:'POST',  
    data: {caller:json},
    success: function(data)
    {
        console.log("ok");
        console.log(json);
    },
    error: function(data)
    {
      console.log("bug");
    }

});
 }
```

the `console.log(json)` works console returns :

```
ok
0033912312312
```

in the test.php file i've tried :

```
<?php
 $moui = $_POST['caller'];
 echo $moui;
 var_dump($moui);
 ?>
```

var dump return `null`

Comment: Your server returns a json and you want to get `Calling` and `Called` object  to get this value `0033912312312` and `0033912312312 `? Right ?

Comment: yes, i need those value in a sql query in php

Comment: Then you have to convert the string to a json object and get your variable what you want. After you just have to call another ajax with parameters `data: {'calling':callingVariable, 'called': calledVariable},` and with php you can get theses variables by calling and called parameter

Comment: edited my question, seems like ajax request works but can't echo $var in php.

Comment: could you `console.log(json)` just before the ajax call and out of ajax callback success. For example you can put console.log(json) below `var json = JSON.parse(test);` I want to know what contains your json variable before calling ajax.

Comment: i've added `console.log(json)` just under `var json = JSON.parse(test);`  returns : `0033912312312`

Comment: I'm waiting you in the chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122392/discussion-between-muimui-and-john

Comment: Merci encore pour ta dispo ;) après moulte test tout fonctionne comme je le voulais !

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the string json to an object

```
var json = JSON.parse(data);
//Now access it like so
json['Calling'];
//or
json.Calling;
```

Comment: thanks, how can i pass json.Calling to php ? do i need a second ajax function ?

Comment: That is definitely an option. I am not sure what the page is doing or I can add a bit more.

Comment: I think you need to more accurately describe what you are attempting to do.